# How do I prevent the elastic search Nest client from injecting the poco name as a slug in the URI for a search?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

The code below will produce a uri with the POCO name included
(`https://demo.com/query/slug1/myIndexName/myPoco/_search`).
What I need is just `https://demo.com/query/slug1/myIndexName/_search`

```cs
var node = new Uri("https://demo.com/query/slug1/");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "myIndexName");

int skipCount = 0;
int takeSize = 100;

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

do
{
    var searchResults = client.Search<myPoco>(x => x.Index("myIndexName")
        .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
        .Must(m =>
            m.Match(mt1 => mt1.OnField(f1 => f1.status).Query("New")))))
        .Skip(skipCount)
        .Take(takeSize));

    foundStuff = (List<myPoco>)searchResults.Documents;

    foreach (foundThing item in searchResults.Documents)
    {
        //DO stuff
    }

    skipCount = skipCount + takeSize;
} while (foundStuff.Count == 100);
```

Am I missing something simple, or is this AFU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not AFU :) [NEST will infer the type name](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/nest-basics.html#_indices_types) to include in the URI from the generic parameter type passed to `Search<T>()`. You can override this easily enough using `.AllTypes()`

```
var searchResults = client.Search<myPoco>(x => x
    .Index("myIndexName")
    // specify all types
    .AllTypes()
    .Query(q => q
    .Bool(b => b
    .Must(m =>
        m.Match(mt1 => mt1.OnField(f1 => f1.status).Query("New")))))
    .Skip(skipCount)
    .Take(takeSize)
);
```

Bear in mind though that this will now search across **all types** in the index and attempt to deserialize each to a `myPoco` type.

In response to your comment, `index` and `type` are two different concepts so if you named the type the same as the index, you would still get `~/{index}/{type}/_search`. With NEST

You can map a default index for a type with `.MapDefaultTypeIndices()` on connection settings

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    .MapDefaultTypeIndices(d => d.Add(typeof(myPoco), "myIndexName"));
```

and similarly, you can map a default type name for a type

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    .MapDefaultTypeNames(d => d.Add(typeof(myPoco), "myType"));
```

You could *abuse* this to map `string.Empty` as the default type name for your type to get the URIs that you want

Comment: Nice!  But if I name the Poco the same as the index with nest infer the correct index?  Or is there a way to map a Poco to an Index and avoid the AllTypes()?

Comment: This is a very useful answer. Thanks :)